# testing an array as property of custom class

Tags: php, restler, swagger

How can i define an array as a property in model class?

let me conclude what i did...

my model class that contains an array

```
 class Author {

        /**
         * @var string {@from body} 
         * name of the Author {@required true}
         */
        public $name = 'Name';

        /**
         * @var string {@type email} {@from body}
         * email id of the Author
         */
        public $email = 'name@domain.com';

        /**
         *  @var array $arr {@type array} array of person
         * {@required true}
         */
        public $arr = array();

    }
```

my function to test throw restler is:

```
/**
     * POST
     * post Author
     *
     * @param {@type Author} $a
     *
     * @return Author
     */
    function postAuthor(Author $a) {
        return $a;
    }
```

when i try to test and class function remotely throw index.html it returns as value:

```
{
    "name":"",
    "email":"",
    "arr":""
}
```

what i need is to return it as follow:

```
{
        "name":"",
        "email":"",
        "arr":[]
    }
```

How and what i have to do to make that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you are talking about Restler Explorer showing the request body with `arr` as a string instead of array

It is because the default response is created as a simple helper to reduce typing and it does not support complex types yet

We are adding Swagger 1.2 support in the new explorer that we are currently working on

It will include an advanced version of the helper to build the request body properly

---

### Update to answer further

If you use Restler 3.0 RC5 (currently only available in `v3` branch) and comment your api model class as shown below you can get it working

```
/**
 *  @var array $arr {@type Person} array of person
 * {@required true}
 */
public $arr = array();
```